# Set ViewBag before rendering _layout.cs file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to set a `ViewBag` property before the _layout.cs file is rendered? I need the `ViewBag` to contain a list that I can use to render the _layout. How can I achieve this?

I have heard about StartUp.cs but I think that's for OWIN and can't be used here, is that correct?

Comment: Last I tried, setting ViewBag properties in your action works in your layout. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `ActionFilter` to set the `ViewBag` property.

```
public class CustomViewBagActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // either inject a property or use the filterContext
        //to get what data you need to use to set the ViewBag

        dynamic ViewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
        ViewBag.Test = "test";
    }
}
```

Then you can either apply it globally like this in `FilterConfig.cs`:

```
filters.Add(new CustomViewBagActionFilter());
```

Or you can decorate your controller or action with it:

```
[CustomViewBagActionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Then you can access the ViewBag property in your _Layout.cs file.  Just make sure to check for null and handle accordingly based on your ViewBag data.